# Perl: Printing out the file where a word occurs

Tags: perl, indexing

I am trying to write a small program that takes from command line file(s) and prints out the number of occurrence of a word from all files and in which file it occurs. The first part, finding the number of occurrence of a word, seems to work well.

However, I am struggling with the second part, namely, finding in which file (i.e. file name) the word occurs. I am thinking of using an array that stores the word but don’t know if this is the best way, or what is the best way.
This is the code I have so far and seems to work well for the part that counts the number of times a word occurs in given file(s):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;

while (<>) {

  my $casefoldstr = lc $_;

  foreach my $str ($casefoldstr =~ /\w+/g) {
    $count{$str}++;
  }
}

foreach my $str (sort keys %count) {
  printf  "$str $count{$str}:\n";
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the indentation on your code. I'm constantly astonished how many people try to write code with seemingly random indentation!

Comment: `perltidy -pbp` ftw!

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed the sort of output that you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array seems reasonable, if you don't visit any file more than once - then you can always just check the last value stored in the array. Otherwise, use a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %count;
my %in_file;
while (<>) {
    my $casefoldstr = lc;
    for my $str ($casefoldstr =~ /\w+/g) {
        ++$count{$str};
        push @{ $in_file{$str} }, $ARGV
            unless ref $in_file{$str} && $in_file{$str}[-1] eq $ARGV;
    }
}

foreach my $str (sort keys %count) {
    printf  "$str $count{$str}: @{ $in_file{$str} }\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The filename is accessible through [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

You can use this to build a nested hash with the filename and word as keys:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'sum';

while (<>) {
    $count{$word}{$ARGV}++ for map +lc, /\w+/g;
}

foreach my $word ( keys %count ) {

    my @files = keys %$word;  # All files containing lc $word
    print "Total word count for '$word': ", sum( @{ $count{$word} }{@files} ), "\n";

    for my $file ( @files ) {
        print "$count{$word}{$file} counts of '$word' detected in '$file'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the output be if the same file is supplied twice?

Comment: @reinierpost if the same file is supplied twice, the word count would double for that file. That particular (and eyebrow-raising?) scenario can be allayed by pre-processing `@ARGV` before it gets to the `while` loop: `use List::Util qw(sum uniq); BEGIN { @ARGV = uniq @ARGV }`

Comment: Or by printing and clearing the hash on [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html).